# QGIS Invalid Geometry when importing a CSV file

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv, qgis-2

I've been learning how to use QGIS for the past couple of weeks, but am having some trouble importing some of my own data as a CSV file. My data looks like:

[image]

Which is giving me the following error:

> 49 records discarded due to invalid geometry definitions.  The
>   following lines were not loaded into QGIS
>   Invalid X or Y fields at line 2 (and so on)

I'm using QGIS on Linux but originally saved the data in Windows/Excel and thought that may have something to do with it, so tried saving it in Libre but no luck there. I also read on a similar question on here that foreign characters in other fields was the problem, so I removed (äüß) them but no luck.

Edit 2:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66281/discussion-on-question-by-maverick-qgis-invalid-geometry-when-importing-a-csv-fi).